# Ok to broaden own question?

Tags: discussion

All comments and the single answer I received so far on a question were not really focused on the subject matter of the question but on a related aspect, so much that I realized it's hard to discuss the two things separately, can I thus modify the question (including the title) slightly so as to state I'm looking for answers on that aspect too?

From what I read edits by the original poster are most of the times considerate legitimate but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Editing questions in response to feedback is highly encouraged.

Invalidating answers that others have already given by changing the question after the fact is highly discouraged.

If the second isn't an issue, edit away!

If it is an issue... try and strike a good balance between improving your question and not making their answer irrelevant.

Comment: OK the second is not applicable, in any case I want to *broaden* the question so no answer would really be invalidated - in my specific case they would actually *become valid* and relevant

Answer (score 5):

Post as new question, assuming old question was legitimate.

- Less jumbled discussion
- You don't wind up in a dilemma of which to accept
- People are rewarded for their hard work originally
- First question is (presumably) still good and worth keeping as a forward-looking resource.

Comment: There is already a good amount of useful comments on the existing question, it would be a pity to waste them (note these were roughly all about the matter I wanted to add to the question - basically to understand and answer correctly to my original question it was useful to firat clarify this other matter)